# Get back original size (height, width) from UIImage load with imageWithData

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage

I just cant find useful information from web.

I have an UIImage which loaded from sqlLite with method imageWithData(NSData*), I just find the height and width of the size both be zero. I wanna get back the original height and width of the image, is it possible? or I do need to store these information separately in sqllite?

Answer (score 1):

Size property of UIImage will work fine.

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:@"slide"];

NSLog(@"WIDTH = %f and HEIGHT = %f\n",image.size.width,image.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using the `UIImage` property `size`?